# Airflow scheduler does not appear to be running after execute a task

Tags: airflow

When there is a task running, Airflow will pop a notice saying the scheduler does not appear to be running and it kept showing until the task finished:

```
The scheduler does not appear to be running. Last heartbeat was received 5 minutes ago.

The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled.
```

Actually, the scheduler process is running, as I have checked the process. After the task finished, the notice will disappear and everything back to normal.

My task is kind of heavy, may running for couple hours.

Answer (score 23):

I think it is expected for Sequential Executor. Sequential Executor runs one thing at a time so it cannot run heartbeat and task at the same time.

Why do you need to use Sequential Executor / Sqlite? The advice to switch to other DB/Executor make perfect sense.

Answer (score 15):

A quick fix could be to run the airflow scheduler separately. Perhaps not the best solution but it did work for me. To do so, run this command in the terminal:

```
airflow scheduler
```

Answer (score 11):

You have started `airflow webserver` and you haven't started your `airflow scheduler`.
Run airflow scheduler in background

```
airflow scheduler > /console/scheduler_log.log &
```

Comment: it's not, the scheduler is running

Comment: why do we need to run the airflow scheduler separately? It should run when we run the docker-compose file right , Mine is working but i need to run airflow scheduler separately

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. 
I switch to postgresql by updating `airflow.cfg` file > `sql_alchemy_conn =postgresql+psycopg2://airflow@localhost:5432/airflow` 
and `executor = LocalExecutor`

This link may help how to set this up locally
https://medium.com/@taufiq_ibrahim/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-ddc087482c14

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and have been trying to troubleshoot this for a while now.

I managed to fix it by setting this value in **airflow.cfg**:

`scheduler_health_check_threshold = 240`

PS: Based on a recent conversation in Airflow Slack Community, it could happen due to contention at the Database side. So, another workaround suggested was to `scale up` the database. In my case, this was not a viable solution.

EDIT:
This was last tested with Airflow Version 2.3.3

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue by deleting airflow-scheduler.pid file.
then
airflow scheduler -D

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, using LocalExecutor and postgresql could fix this error.

Running Airflow locally, following the instruction, https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html.

It has the default config

```
executor = SequentialExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////Users/yourusername/airflow/airflow.db
```

It will use SequentialExecutor and sqlite by default, and it will have this "The scheduler does not appear to be running." error.

To fix it, I followed Jarek Potiuk's advice. I changed the following config:

```
executor = LocalExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql://postgres:masterpasswordforyourlocalpostgresql@localhost:5432
```

And then I rerun the "airflow db init"

```
airflow db init

airflow users create \
--username admin \
--firstname Peter \
--lastname Parker \
--role Admin \
--email spiderman@superhero.org
```

After the db inited. Run

```
airflow webserver --port 8080
airflow scheduler
```

This fixed the airflow scheduler error.

Comment: okay, I followed the official tutorial you linked and I see the config parameters you mentioned. However I do not have a postgres service running. What should I do in order to start this service? Can I use docker? Is there a way for me to check what Postgre versions are compatible with the Airflow version I have?

Comment: You can install and run Postgre from your local machine.

Better way to use docker_compose to run both airflow and postgres in containers.

such as using this one

https://github.com/marclamberti/docker-airflow

Answer (score 1):

Check the **airflow-scheduler.err** and **airflow-scheduler.log** files.

I got an error like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myVM/venv/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lockfile/pidlockfile.py", ine 77, in acquire
write_pid_to_pidfile(self.path)
File "/home/myVM/venv/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lockfile/pidlockfile.py", line 161, in write_pid_to_pidfile
pidfile_fd = os.open(pidfile_path, open_flags, open_mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/home/myVM/venv/py_env/airflow-scheduler.pid'

I removed the existing **airflow-scheduler.pid** file and started the scheduler again by `airflow scheduler -D`. It was working fine then.

Answer (score 1):

Our problem is that the file "logs/scheduler.log" is too large, 1TB. After cleaning this file everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If it matters: somehow, the `-D` flag causes a lot of problems for me. The `airflow webserver -D` immediately crashes after starting, and `airflow scheduler -D` somehow does next to nothing for me.

Weirdly enough, it works without the **detach** flag. This means I can just run the program normally, and make it run in the background, with e.g. `nohup airflow scheduler &`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using sqlite. There was a special message in Airflow logs: `ERROR - Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting max_threads to 1`. If you use only 1 thread, the scheduler will be unavailable while executing a dag.

So if use sqlite, try to switch to another database. If you don't, check `max_threads` value in your `airflow.cfg`.

Comment: it' not working , still showing the same. I modified the `max_threads=10`, and restarted the scheduler.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: I use Mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

On Composer page, click on your environment name, and it will open the **Environment details**, go to the **PyPIPackages** tab.

Click on **Edit** button, increase the any package version.

For example:
[image]

I increased the version of **pymsql** packages, and this restarted the airflow environment, it took a while for it to update. Once it is done, I'm no longer have this error.

You can also add a Python package, it will restart the airflow environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue after changing the airflow timezone. I then restarted the airflow-scheduler and it works. You can also check if the airflow-scheduler and airflow-worker are on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when `AIRFLOW_HOME` is not set.
By setting `AIRFLOW_HOME` to the correct path, the indicated executor will be selected.

Answer (score -3):

After change executor from `SequentialExecutor` to `LocalExecutor`, it works!

in `airflow.cfg`:

```
executor = LocalExecutor
```

Comment: I need to use SequentialExecutor.

Comment: Just a reference:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/sequential.html
The SequentialExecutor is the default executor when you first install airflow. It is the only executor that can be used with sqlite since sqlite doesn’t support multiple connections. This executor will only run one task instance at a time. For production use case, please use other executors.